# Is there a independent maven artifact used as a docbook generate tools

Tags: maven, docbook, docbook-5

Actually there is a maven plugin [docbkx-maven-plugin](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net/docbkx-samples/manual.html) which can generate pdf, html or other format in the maven project, but the problem is you need to configure more about xsl template, css, or if you want to highlight the source code, support other language like Chinese, you also need to do more configures, so Is there a independent maven artifact used as a docbook generate tools, includes following features:

1. include the dtd files
2. code highlight support
3. non-english support, means can generate pdf like in Chinese content
4. have a default xsl template for generate html, pdf

Comment: Have you tried that already or are you searching for a ready-to-use solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried already, and found the template, code highlight ... are a hard work.

Comment: We implemented the needed actions in a ant build file and use the maven-ant-plugin to call. Far from being 'the maven way' but this is just much more flexible.

Comment: Cool, actually maven way or ant way are almost the same, just convenient to generate the corresponding html/pdf files. Now I'm using the basis file extracted form [citrus](https://github.com/christophd/citrus) and working well when generate html. But when try to generate pdf include non-english, the font is a problem.